# Bash variable usage

Tags: bash, variables

I am confused by how to use variables in Bash. Please see the following example. I am not able to figure out why Bash isn't able to recognize the variable within (). Can anybody please help me understand what is going on.

```
$echo $SHELL
 /bin/bash
$export TestC=/Users
$echo $TestC
 /Users
$export TestD=$TestC/ABCD
$echo $TestD
/Users/ABCD
$export TestD=$(TestC)/ABCD
-bash: TestC: command not found
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Because that's not at all how you specify a variable name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why did you use parentheses?

Answer (score 4):

When referencing a bash variable you either use `$` then the name, as in `$TestC` or you can put braces around the name like `${TestC}`.

`$(...)` is a subshell syntax called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) that will execute the command inside the parens then "return" the stdout of that command.

Read all about parameter/variable expansion [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), which also shows a lot of the extra things you can do with the parameter expansion when using braces.